# Inequality for symmetric polynomial functions of log concave variables

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, inequalities, symmetric-functions

Let $(x_i)_{i \ge 1}$ be a log-concave (resp. log-convex) sequence of non-negative real variables. In other words, for $i \ge 2$, we have $x_i^2 \ge x_{i-1}x_{i+1}$ (resp. $x_i^2 \le x_{i-1}x_{i+1}$).

For brevity, let us denote $h_{m,n}$ (resp. $e_{m,n}$) the complete homogeneous (resp. elementary ) symmetric polynomials of degree $m$ on the $n$ variables $x_1,\cdot \cdot,x_n$

$$ h_{m,n}= h_m (x_1,\cdot \cdot ,x_n):= \sum_{1\le i_1\le \cdot \cdot \le i_m \le n}x_{i_1}\cdot\cdot x_{i_m} $$
$$ e_{m,n}= e_m (x_1,\cdot \cdot ,x_n):= \sum_{1\le i_1\lt \cdot \cdot \lt i_m \le n}x_{i_1}\cdot\cdot x_{i_m}. $$

> Then, when the variables are log-concave, the following inequalities
> conjecturally hold for all $j,p,n$ such that $1 \le j \le p \le n$
> $$ \frac{h_{n-p,p+1}}{h_{n-p,p}} \le \frac{h_{n-j,j+1}}{h_{n-j,j}}
>  \cdot \frac{h_{p-j,j}}{h_{p-j,j+1}} $$ $$
>  \frac{e_{n-p,n}}{e_{n-p,n-1}} \ge \frac{e_{n-j,n}}{e_{n-j,n-1}}
>  \cdot\frac{e_{p-j,p-1}}{e_{p-j,p}} $$ and the inequalities are
> reversed when the variables are log-convex.

A proof of the above inequalities would entail an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4652848/130022) about Stirling numbers, which is the special log-concave case $x_i=i$.

ADDENDUM: The following generalization can also be conjectured:

Let $(x_i)_{i \ge 1}$ be a log-concave  sequence of non-negative real variables.
Let $1\le a_1 \lt a_2 \cdot\cdot \lt a_k$ be a sequence of $k$ positive natural numbers. Let $m =a_k-a_1$ and $\beta_i= a_{i+1}-a_i$. The $\beta_i$ make a *composition* of $m$ in $k-1$ parts.

The following inequalities hold:
$$ \prod_{i} \frac{h_{\beta_i,a_i+1}}{h_{\beta_i,a_i}} \le \frac{h_{m,a_1+1}}{h_{m,a_1}}
 $$ $$
 \prod_{i} \frac{e_{\beta_i,a_{i+1}-1}}{e_{\beta_i,a_{i+1}}} \le \frac{e_{m,a_k-1}}{e_{m,a_k}} $$
where the product is over all the parts of the composition and the inequalities are
reversed when the variables are log-convex.

Remarks.

(i) These are equalities when all the $X_i$ are equal. Actually these are equalities if and only if $X_i=X_1 q^{i-1}$, in which case the symetric polynomials reduce to $q$-binomial coefficients.

(ii) Actually the initial sequence $(a_i)$ does not need to be strictly increasing, because if not, it can still be sorted in increasing order. But in the products the terms corresponding to duplicates $a_i$ don't contribute to the product.

(iii) particular values of $k$. When $k=1$, the inequalities are trivially $1=1$. When $k=2$ these are also equalities. The first interesting case is when $k=3$ as above.

(iv) for the case $k=m \ge 3$ and  $a_i=i$, there is direct proof. All $\beta_i=1$ and then (in the $h$-case) we need to prove

$$ \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{h_{1,i+1}}{h_{1,i}} \le \frac{h_{k-1,2}}{h_{k-1,1}}
 $$
which after reduction is
$$ \sum_{j=2}^{k-1}X_1^{k-1}X_{j+1} \le \sum_{j=2}^{k-1} X_1^{k-j}X_2^j .$$

But this is true because for each $j \ge 2$, $ X_1^{k-1}X_{j+1} \le  X_1^{k-j}X_2^j$ thanks to the log-concavity of $X_j$.

(v) I also have a direct proof in the $h$-case, for $k=3$ when $a_1=1$ and $a_2=2$.

(vi) For each composition of  $m$, the number of monomials (counted with multiplicities) is the same in $$ h_{m,a_1}\prod_{i}h_{\beta_i,a_i+1}  $$ as in $$ h_{m,a_1+1}\prod_{i}h_{\beta_i,a_i}.$$ Then it would suffice to find a pairing between them such that one monomial would be larger than the other thanks to the log-concavity. I believe that such a pairing is always possible but I have not been able to construct the corresponding bijection so far.

(vii) The generalization is actually equivalent to the initial
statement. Indeed, for a composition of $m$ in $k-1$ parts,
adding the last (resp. first) two parts produces a composition of $m$ in $k-2 $ parts. Then, provided that the two-parts case ($k =3$) is true, an induction argument can be used for the general inequality involving $e$ (resp. $h$).